# Rails: Error running wkhtmltopdf -- (error while loading shared libraries)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

When my app runs (or when I run from commandline) the wkhtmltopdf command I get the following error: (showing it from command line)

```
#> wkhtmltopdf 
wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I noticed the lib is indeed in the `/usr/lib` folder but not the `/lib` folder. Does it matter which one of these it is in? Is there any way to get it to recognize it?

```
#> ls -l /usr/lib/libXrender.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    19 Feb 17 07:20 /usr/lib/libXrender.so -> libXrender.so.1.3.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    19 Feb 17 07:20 /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1 -> libXrender.so.1.3.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39184 Jan 29  2010 /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1.3.0

#> ls -l /lib/libXrender.so*
ls: cannot access /lib/libXrender.so*: No such file or directory
```

I also checked dependencies of the lib

```
# ldd /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0x00002b9cb5afd000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00002b9cb5e04000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0x00002b9cb6143000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00002b9cb6347000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b9cb654d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000555555554000)
```

This is running on an EngineYard gentoo server

Comment: For the googler: It's now best to install `wkhtmltopdf` by using the provided OS package, e.g. the `deb` package, which automatically installs `libXrender` as well as other needed dependencies too: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/tag/0.12.5

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The Unix packages x11-libs/libXext and x11-libs/libXrender are dependencies

Gentoo:

```
sudo emerge libXext libXrender
```

PDFkit wiki also explains in more detail how to get wkhtmltopdf working on engine yard.
[PDFkit wiki](https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit/wiki)

Debian or Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libxrender1
```

Comment: That post had instructions, but I noticed it was referencing the i386 version so I changed to referencing the amd64 and it worked ... so I updated the wiki to include instructions for 64bit instance.

Comment: This worked for me!  However, on Debian I also had to run `sudo apt-get install libext6`.

Comment: On Debian 11, I had to run `sudo apt-get install libxrender1 libxext-dev`

Answer (score 38):

I had the same, issue on Debian Squeeze, amd64. Installing libxrender1 solved the issue for me.

```
sudo apt-get install libxrender1
```

Answer (score 32):

I need also do after:

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1
```

Answer (score 13):

Ran into this today on a RHEL7 machine running the [static version](https://github.com/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64) of wkhtmltopdf.  Solution was to install a few dependencies:

```
yum install libXrender libXext fontconfig
```

Comment: After doing this on mine it showed Black boxes instead of text. I had to install these two packages to make the text work: `xorg-x11-font-utils` and `xorg-x11-fonts-Type1`

Answer (score 9):

With Ubuntu 16 (from a fresh Docker install):

```
apt install -y libxrender1 libxext6
```

Answer (score 8):

If your system is 64 bits, and your software requires 32 bits libs, you need to add the flag "i386",

for example on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libxrender1:i386
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having the exact same problem! The solution, to me, was to install the 64bit version of wkhtmltoimage.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue after rebuilding one of my containers, while before everything was working fine. All the answers I found online didn't work for me, so here's how I troubleshooted and resolved:

**1. Check if all dependencies are there:**

`ldd path/to/your/binary/file/wkhtmltopdf-amd64`

Here's what I got from that

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffded169000)
libXrender.so.1 => not found
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f117bab0000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f117b806000)
libXext.so.6 => not found
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f117b4cc000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f117b2b2000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f117b0ae000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f117aea6000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f117ac89000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f117a907000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f117a5fe000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f117a3e8000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f117a01e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f117bcf3000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f1179df5000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f1179bd0000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f11799ae000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f11797aa000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f11795a4000)
```

Where I got "not found" means the dependencies were missing

**2. apt update and install**

Update your apt, as it's likely it won't find the libraries needed to install

`apt-get update`

Now I installed the missing dependencies that had the "not found" in the results above. Take note that for the `libxrender` and `libxext` I had to install `libxrender-dev` and `libxext-dev`.

`apt-get install -y libxrender-dev libxext-dev`

Answer (score 1):

> sudo apt-get install xvfb

to install the dependency package.

Update the node-modules wkhtmltopdf index.js

> wkhtmltopdf.command = 'wkhtmltopdf'; to 'wkhtmltopdf.command =
>   'xvfb-run wkhtmltopdf';'

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue on running a Rails 5.2 application on an Ubuntu 18.04 production server, the issue was that there were missing dependencies for `libXrender` on the server

**Here's how I solved it**:

Run the command below to search for the missing dependencies:

```
sudo apt-cache search libXrender
```

This will display the output below:

```
libxrender-dev - X Rendering Extension client library (development files)
libxrender1 - X Rendering Extension client library
libreoffice - office productivity suite (metapackage)
```

If you're running on a production server, simply install `libxrender1` only (for rendering PDFs):

```
sudo apt-get install libxrender1
```

Also, if possible run upgrades for outdated libraries on your server:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Once all these have been completed, simply restart your application server (If your application server is `puma` and if your setup systemd for the server):

```
sudo systemctl restart puma
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is an executable version of wkhtmltopdf distributed in a UPX compressed format, ldd and file will both report that this file is statically linked even though the payload requires shared libraries.

To check try

strings  | fgrep UPX

If you see any "UPX" id strings then install upx and use "upx -d" on a copy of the file (as upx works in place) and then run ldd on the uncompressed file.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (for future google searchs), on an Amazon Linux 2018:03

```
yum localinstall -y https://repo.almalinux.org/almalinux/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/libpng15-1.5.30-7.el8.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall -y https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox-0.12.6-1.amazonlinux2.x86_64.rpm
```