# Snappy PDF Laravel 5.2 not working

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I am trying to use Snappy PDF from barrvdh but I'm getting an error.

My code is as below

```
 public function test_pdf($invoice_id)
{
    $invoices = InvoiceHeader::where('id', $invoice_id)->first();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('billing.invoice.test', ['invoice' => $invoices]);
    return $pdf->download('invoice'.$invoices->id.'.pdf');
}
```

And my error is as below:

> ErrorException in PDFController.php line 28:
>   Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\PDFController::test_pdf()

Comment: You are missing `$invoice_id` while calling test_pdf

Comment: i fixed that but i am getting a new error now file_put_contents(/var/www/html/bootstrap/cache/services.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: Are you using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue, you missed `$invoice_id` while calling `test_pdf` function

And for the second issue :

With your terminal, type this :

```
cd path/to/your/project
php artisan cache:clear
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache/services.php
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: now i get this error The exit status code '127' says something went wrong:
stderr: "sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: not found

Comment: Look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035601/error-running-wkhtmltopdf-error-while-loading-shared-libraries

Comment: i followed steps on there but I'm still getting the error

Comment: the this is that its not finding the file. and i have moved the file to the required path and yet its not working, i don't know what I'm doing wrong and I'm not reinstalling the whole development environment

Comment: I have a new error now The exit status code '134' says something went wrong:
stderr: "QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Aborted
"
stdout: ""
command: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --lowquality '/tmp/knp_snappy579fcbbab48fb5.37600980.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy579fcbbab49731.67956603.pdf'.